# How to use google's api to set up a delivery range

Tags: api

I am looking to implement google maps for my restaurant food ordering application. I am looking to set up the delivery range parameters using google maps, so that deliveries won't go out of the restaurants delivery range.
They way I want to accomplish this, is to have the user enter their address before they start ordering. Then my application will validate the address, and make sure its not outside of the restaurants delivery range, based on whats set up on google maps.
Can anyone help me out and point me to the right direction on implementing this kind of feature.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I try to do the same ... 
to get geolocation use this: http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/draggable.html

Comment: Cosmin, Thanks your reply. Have you successfully implemented for an online ordering application?